# Getting type declarations for Tries right

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-declaration

I'm using the [`list-tries` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-tries):

```hs
import qualified Data.ListTrie.Patricia.Map as TM
import qualified Data.ListTrie.Patricia.Set as TS
import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

I have a list of strings, which I want to store in a Trie-Map consisting of Trie-Sets, like this:

```hs
-- vocabs :: [String]
trie = TM.fromListWith' (flip TS.union) $ map (\v->(sort v, TS.singleton v)) vocabs
```

(this is for looking up a set of letters in the outer trie, then looking up a specific combination of letters in the resulting trie).

I can understand that Haskell does not know which exact type the trie has, because I have nowhere specified which type of map to use. I thought I could do this by adding the declaration

```hs
trie :: TM.TrieMap Map.Map Char (TS.TrieSet Map.Map Char)
```

but it seems not to be enough. I'm still getting error messages like

> No instance for `(Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Map.Map Char)`
>        arising from a use of `TrieM.fromListWith'`
>
> Possible fix:
>        add an instance declaration for
>        `(Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Map.Map Char)`
>
> In the expression: `TrieM.fromListWith' TrieS.union`
>
> In the expression: …

and similar ones for the of `TS.singleton`, `TM.lookup`, `TS.member` and `TS.findMin`.

I don't seem to get the actual problem, and also don't know how to add type declaration to [inline] expressions (I've seen it a few times, but didn't get the syntax). Could you please help me out?

Comment: I think it's a package version mismatch, see below (doesn't fit in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem.

Without the signature for `trie`, I get - unsurprisingly - an *ambiguous type variable* error (well, two), for the reason stated in the question, together with a possible cause (that really is the cause, it's the monomorphism restriction), and two probable fixes (disabling the monomorphism restriction makes it compile, but giving an explicit type signature is the better fix). The error message is appended below for overinterested souls (it's from 7.6.1).

With the type signature, it compiles cleanly.

In the light of that, I cannot diagnose the problem with certainty, but experience together with the error message you got provide a probable cause.

You got a very specific message that the required instance is not in scope:

```
No instance for (Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Map.Map Char) arising from a use of TrieM.fromListWith'

Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Map.Map Char)
```

On the other hand, the list-tries package explicitly provides such an instance.

The typical cause for such a situation is that there are two distinct classes or two distinct types involved that come from different versions of the same package.

In this case, you have likely built `list-tries` against one version of `containers`, and later installed a different version of `containers`, and the `import qualified Data.Map as Map` imports the `Map.Map` type from the newer package version, while the instance in `list-tries` is for the older version.

Check whether you have more than one version of `containers` installed with

```
ghc-pkg list containers
```

Check on which version of `containers` your `list-tries` depends with

```
ghc-pkg describe list-tries
```

In the `depends` field of the output of that, there will appear something like

```
containers-0.5.0.0-e49be7a240765a4edc5c09f677ec6a81
```

listing the package version and the ABI hash of the `containers` package `list-tries` was built with.

If the version doesn't correspond to the newest version of `containers` you have installed, the above situation arises unless the version of `containers` to use is explicitly specified when invoking GHC, either directly with a `-package` flag, or indirectly via a `.cabal` file.

If that is the case, you can

- explicitly specify the version of `containers` to use every time you use `list-tries`
- unregister the newer version(s)of `containers` (could break other packages)
- rebuild `list-tries` against the newer version of `containers`

---

```
TrieTest.hs:12:8:
    No instance for (Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map map0 Char)
      arising from a use of TM.fromListWith'
    The type variable `map0' is ambiguous
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      trie :: TM.TrieMap map0 Char (TS.TrieSet map1 Char)
        (bound at TrieTest.hs:12:1)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Eq k =>
               Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.AList k
        -- Defined in `Data.ListTrie.Base.Map'
      instance Ord k => Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Map.Map k
        -- Defined in `Data.ListTrie.Base.Map'
      instance Enum k =>
               Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.WrappedIntMap k
        -- Defined in `Data.ListTrie.Base.Map'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map map0 Char)
    In the expression: TM.fromListWith' (flip TS.union)
    In the expression:
      TM.fromListWith' (flip TS.union)
      $ map (\ v -> (sort v, TS.singleton v)) vocabs
    In an equation for `trie':
        trie
          = TM.fromListWith' (flip TS.union)
            $ map (\ v -> (sort v, TS.singleton v)) vocabs

TrieTest.hs:12:31:
    No instance for (Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map map1 Char)
      arising from a use of `TS.union'
    The type variable `map1' is ambiguous
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      trie :: TM.TrieMap map0 Char (TS.TrieSet map1 Char)
        (bound at TrieTest.hs:12:1)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Eq k =>
               Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.AList k
        -- Defined in `Data.ListTrie.Base.Map'
      instance Ord k => Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Map.Map k
        -- Defined in `Data.ListTrie.Base.Map'
      instance Enum k =>
               Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.WrappedIntMap k
        -- Defined in `Data.ListTrie.Base.Map'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Data.ListTrie.Base.Map.Map map1 Char)
    In the first argument of `flip', namely `TS.union'
    In the first argument of TM.fromListWith', namely `(flip TS.union)'
    In the expression: TM.fromListWith' (flip TS.union)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I really have updated `containers` to 5.x while `list-tries` relied on 4.x. How do I rebuild against the new version, will I have to do another `cabal install list-tries` or is there a better option?

Comment: No, `cabal install`ing it is the easiest. It doesn't have many dependencies, so it shouldn't take long even if dependencies need to be reinstalled. I'd `ghc-pkg unregister list-tries` first, if you have stuff depending on `list-tries`, that will cause a warning, then you have to decide whether it's worth the trouble, or if unregistering `containers-0.5` might be better (or explicit `-package` options/.cabal files; then `cabal install -v list-tries --dry-run` to see what it would do. If nothing needs to be reinstalled and `containers-0.5.x` is selected, `cabal install list-tries`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need containers-0.5 on the same project :-) There was also a dependency mismatch, as binary did not work with the new containers. I did a `cabal install -v list-tries --reinstall --upgrade-dependencies`, and all seems to work now. Thanks again!

Comment: Run `ghc-pkg check` to see whether upgrading dependencies broke anything. If it did, it's far better to catch it early and reinstall the broken stuff built against the new dependencies pronto.